# Current consumption calculation and also battery life calculation

Tags: power, batteries, current

I'm a newbie, I need to know how to calculate the current consumption of circuit and also how do  calculation of  the battery life according to the circuit's current consumption? I'm using Li-Po battery ( 400mAH , 3.7 V, 1.48 WH). Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What's the load?

Comment: What is the lowest voltage that the LiPo can drop down to before the circuit no longer works reliably?

Comment: you can refer this [How to calculate battery life][1]


  [1]: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-to-calculate-battery-life?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult because the voltage across the load is probably going to change as the battery wears out. The simplest case is as follows; if you know the current to the load (given in Amps), and you know that your battery is 400mAH, then by simple integration, you can figure battery life by the following calculation.

[image]

Now, to expand on this logic, if you can plot current over the usable lifetime of the battery, you will be able to get a more fin grained picture of the estimated battery life.